# Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException with BufferedReader

Tags: java, multithreading, nullpointerexception, bufferedreader, serversocket

I am implementing a server/client program. I need create multiple thread in server to handle message from client. When I compiled the code, there is an error

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
at server.run(Program.java:59)
```

Line 59 is

```
BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new 
                 InputStreamReader(sSock.getInputStream()));
```

which is used to read message from client side.

My program code is:

```
class Program {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
      // Program runs as a Server
      if(args.length == 2) {
      String host = args[0];
      int port = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
      String fileName = "serverFile";
      ServerSocket sSock = null;

      // Open a server socket.
      try {
         sSock = new ServerSocket(port);
      }catch(Exception e) {
         System.out.println("Error: cannot open server socket");
         System.exit(1); // Handle exceptions.
      }

      System.out.println("Server is listening on port " + port);

      while(true) {
         new server(sSock.accept(), fileName).start();
      }
    }
  }
}

class server extends Thread {
  // Thread t = Thread.currentThread();

   Socket sSock = null;
   String fileName = null;
   server(Socket sScok,String fileName) {
   this.sSock = sSock;
   this.fileName = fileName;
 }
  @Override
  public void run() {
    try {
      BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new 
                     InputStreamReader(sSock.getInputStream()));
      PrintWriter sendOut = new PrintWriter(sSock.getOutputStream(), 
                     true);
      String s = inFromClient.readLine();
      System.out.println("receive string " + s + "from client");
      sendOut.println("send Ack to you");
    }catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Error: " + e);
   }
 }
}
```

I have been struggled for a long time...Someone can help would be great.

Comment: Your `server` constructor has an argument called `sScok`, which is never used. Did you mean it to be `sSock`? Also, class names should start with capital letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Socket sSock = null;` to begin with, and is never updated

In your constructor you have

```
server(Socket sScok,String fileName) {
this.sSock = sSock;
```

The input is `sScok` instead of `sSock`, it looks to be a typo, but has a huge effect on your code

Fixing the typo, `server(Socket sSock, String fileName) {` should do the trick

Comment: Thanks so much! Yes! The typo results in the compile error.

Comment: It does not allow me to mark this within the first 3 minutes after receiving your answer. I mark it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't initiated `sSock` so `sSock.getInputStream()` throws an exception. The `sSock = new ServerSocket(port);` line in your main method initiates a **different** variable named `sSock` than the one in your `server` class.